# UIPageViewController in Container not displaying other View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Ok, could someone please help with my Swift code that I'm trying to fix.
I have read other question on here similar to mine but to no avail unfortunately.

The problem is that I have a UIPageViewController in a Container but when I test it on the iPhone, it won't display the two views I have set (there is actually 9 views but only put 2 in the code for now so I can get it working).

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class pvController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vController1")
        let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vController2")

        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)

        setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex! - 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex! + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I did initially try doing it with SwipeGestureRecogniser although I couldn't get it to work/figure it out.

Also I am fairly new to this so it may be something simple that I just can't figure out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42197113/5461400

Comment: I have check your code its working fine Can you tell me what issue you are facing ? I am getting all ViewController on pageviewcontroller with swipe.

Comment: It is just when I load the app, it just displays a white screen and not the views I have created. I'm not sure what the issue is. Not sure if it is contributing but the Container's class is `UIViewController`, the Page View Controller's class is `UIPageViewController` and the views that are meant to be displayed is class `pvController` but I think that is right.

Comment: Also using that link in first comment, trying to change parts to match that with no luck either.

Comment: Facing the exact same issue. I have two UIPageViewControllers embedded through Containers into my initial View Controller and no content is displayed. The areas respond to swipes (i.e. the Before and After methods of the Data Source execute), but no content is ever displayed. Did you ever figure it out?